# Scheduling: Minimum number of meetings needed to meet all candidates

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Imagine I'm a recruiter and I have a list of $n$ candidates, each of whom are free for different continuous periods throughout the day. I need to conduct group interviews for each candidate (a group interview must have more than 1 candidate, of course) and I want to choose the fewest time slots possible to meet all candidates at least once algorithmically.

For example, I may have 2 candidates free for 2 hours, 2 for 3 hours, 1 for 4 hours and another for 5 in a 10 hour day. Their free times may align like below:

[image]

In this case, an optimal selection of time slots would be 4 and 8. I started to tackle this problem by defining a greedy algorithm which chooses the highest density time slot at each iteration. This works, in the example above (choosing 4, which has 4 overlapping times, and then 8, which has the the next most times). However, it fails on the following input:

[image]

Here, the algorithm chooses 7, 4, 8 as the optimal time slots, when the best solution is 4, 8 only. There are several such inputs.

What's a provably optimal algorithm which finds the best time slots to book my group interviews?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), and a provably optimal solution method is integer linear programming, with a binary decision variable $x_t$ for each time slot $t$.  For each candidate $c$, let $T_c$ be the set of time slots during which $c$ is available. The problem is to minimize $\sum_t x_t$ subject to linear constraints:
$$\sum_{t\in T_c} x_t \ge 1$$
for each $c$.